# Magento Installer: Step 2:Add Database: defect note

Tags: mysql, database, magento

first please excuse my bad English-I try my best!
As a complete amateur I have to install the E commerce System Magento (note: I use Wamp Server and FileZilla). In the installation process step 2 "add a database" I am not getting any further. If I put in all the required data:

```
Database Server: localhost

Database User: web1...

Database Userpassword: My....

Database Name: usr_web1....
```

a defect note appears. It is either: "Database 'usr_web...' does not exist or specified database server user does not have privileges to access this database." When I also put in the (optional) database passwort the following defect note appears:  **"SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'web....'@'localhost' (using password: YES)"**.
If anyone of you can help me I would be so greateful!!! I have already researched so much but don't get any further.
Thank you, kind regards,
Mara

Answer (score 2):

Please check followigs

Make sure you have reset all the file permissions for your installation according to the Magento Wiki [documentation](http://magento.com/help/documentation)

On your MySQL server, create a username, password and database name that matches the one of your previous server.

If you are still getting error messages, verify that the username, password and database name **/app/etc/local.xml**

If this do not work, then follow detailed Magento Wiki to move your [installation](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/groups/227/moving_magento_to_another_server) and see where you went wrong.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I will try to implement your tips!!